# Does dplyr across work for remote database?

Tags: r, dplyr

I systematically either get the follow errors, depending if I use mutate(across(condition, function) or mutate(across(condition, ~ function(.x)):

- no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class
  "formula"
- no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of
  class "function"

And since you pass your function to across with either...I *think* it doesn't work but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: My first guess would be that `across` does not translate into the database language. But without a [mcve] this is very difficult to answer as it likely depends a lot on how you are connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This just got fixed! Same day...Hadley!
https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/480